# Passing UIBezierPath to view class for drawing

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am making a level based game with many different objects, all different.  In each level, there will be different amounts of each type of object.  Thus, I have been trying to make the drawing part as generic as possible so that all I have to do is pass in the coords and it will automatically draw.  To do this, I have made a protocol that forces each object class to implement the method getBP(), which returns the UIBezierPath to draw for each.  Then, the view class just has to say

```
Object.getBP().fill()
```

However, this has been leading to some strange problems.  The object does not draw at the correct coordinates.  The y coordinate is correct, but the x coordinate puts it always at the left of the screen.  I think it may be the fact that the Bezier Path is not being created in the view class.  Here is my code in Surface.swift (this is meant to draw a surface in the game):

```
func getBP() -> UIBezierPath {
    var rect:CGRect
    var length:Double = getSurfaceVector().getMagnitude()//length of the surface
    var cx = points.1.x+(points.0.x-points.1.x)//center coords of the surface
    var cy = points.1.y+(points.0.y-points.1.y)
    var bp = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(CGFloat(cx - length/2), CGFloat(cy-RECT_HEIGHT/2), CGFloat(length), CGFloat(RECT_HEIGHT)), cornerRadius: CGFloat(5))
    let transform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double(angle)*(Double(M_PI)/Double(180))))
    bp.applyTransform(transform)
    return bp
}
```

points is just a tuple with the start and end points of the surface.  RECT_HEIGHT is the height of the rectangle that is drawn to represent the surface. angle is the angle from horizontal of the surface.

Creating the surface in View.swift, I do this:

```
Surface(fixed: true, points: (Vector(x: 50, y:100), Vector(x: Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width), y: 100)))
```

I add that surface to the array of objects in the game.  I draw it in the View.swift file by saying

```
surface.stroke()
```

The surface draws on the screen with a y value of 100, but it is centered at x = 0 so that it is half on and half off of the screen.  Also, it doesn't draw at the angle - it is always horizontal.  Is there some better way of doing this?  What is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `points.0` and `points.1` (are they globals?), but the lines `var cx = points.1.x+(points.0.x-points.1.x)` and  `var cy = points.1.y+(points.0.y-points.1.y)` don't find centres - they are exactly equivalent to `var cx = points.0.x` and `var cy = points.0.y`. I suspect you wanted to divide the second (delta) terms by 2.0 ...

Comment: Wow, I really can't believe I missed that. Thanks! That still doesn't explain why the rotation isn't working. Do have any idea why?

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the context - several of the 'parameters' are defined outside of the scope of the function (including `angle`).

Comment: Ok, on further inspection I was basing angle off the endpoints of the surface but I hadn't initialized the endpoints by the time I did the calculation. Thank you so much for your help!